# VPN - это туннелированный виртуальный канал до proxy с шифрованием?

Tags: proxy, vpn

Если говорить о коммерческом VPN(Для конечного юзера), можно ли утверждать, что это просто туннелированный виртуальный канал до proxy-сервера с шифрованием?

Comment: Нет, так нельзя утверждать. VPN = Virtual Private Network. Это виртуальная, обособленная от глобальной сети (интернета) сеть. Предназначена в первую очередь что бы какая либо машина могла из любой точки интернета оказаться внутри небольшой внутренней сети (обычно сети предприятия). Ни о каких прокси речи вообще не идет. Шифрование так же не является обязательным атрибутом

Comment: @Mike, да, но я говорю о решениях для широкого круга пользователей, а не для выстраивания сети между офисами компании. По факту же, пользователю предоставляется виртуальный канал до сервера, который выступает в виде прокси для выхода в Интернет, а шифрование обычно включено. Разве не так?

Comment: Канал - это канал, проксей он никак быть не может. Да, он предоставляет доступ внутрь некой обособленной сети, так, как будто ваш компьютер находится внутри нее. И из это сети, для всех входящих в нее компьютеров предоставляется доступ в интернет, возможно напрямую с выделенных ip, возможно через NAT с внутренних адресов. Да, конечно это может быть способом обеспечения доступа к прокси (что само по себе глупо, ибо сама прокся могла бы поддерживать шифрованное соединение и авторизовать пользователя, vpn был бы ни к чему).

Comment: @Mike канал это просто эффективный способ доставки.

Comment: @kaylil_01 это лишь один из частных случаев. С широким кругом вообще всё плохо: многие штуки, которые называют VPN, вообще не являются VPN. В частности, все браузерные расширения с «VPN» в названии на самом деле не VPN.

Comment: просто термин "прокси" довольно узкий - это программа, обычно слушающая на одном единственном порту и позволяющая пробросить через себя соединения только клиентам которые готовы говорить с ней на ее протоколе (а зачастую и только до серверов говрящих на другом конкретном протоколе, например http). А в vpn вашему клиенту не надо быть готовым говорить на каком то конкретном протоколе, после того как канал установлен, потому что вас выпустят в интернет (как) через обычный роутер.

Comment: @Mike так в этом и суть, не факт, что выпустят, поэтому для обычных людей, которые хотят "защитить соединение", по факту VPN будет просто шифрованным каналом с проксированием в Интернет.

Comment: @Mike ну хорошо, возможно, термин"проксирование" не лучший, так как сеть идентифицировать будет себя как локальная. Тогда по-другому: виртуальный канал с шифрованием и доступом в Интернет.

Comment: Ну доступ в интернет, для термина vpn не является обязательным. А так, да, в том понимании о котором вы спрашиваете, это виртуальный канал в сеть, которая имеет доступ в интернет

Comment: @Mike спасибо за хороший диалог, можете составить ответ, отмечу верным.